# React Native Expo Bare WF stuck on splash screen in prod mode only (in store)

Tags: react-native, expo

My react native App is build on Expo. I started in Managed Workflow and decided to eject to the Bare WorkFlow for using Stripe-React-Native module that require that.

After ejecting, i have decided to use the EAS (Expo build and publish service).

I have launched eas build for Both ios and Android. And no errors where thrown on ios side. I have published the app, installed it and it worked like a charm for all my users.

Android part is less smooth. A lot of errors where throwns at build phase and i have modified build.grade and mainactivity a lot for succeeding in building. I managed to do so, build a bundle, and publish it on the Play Store. But the app install, launch and get stuck on Splash Screen.

I decided to build and apk instead and run it from Android Studio for debugging purpose with logcat.

I think that the most interesting part of logcat output is that :

```
2021-05-31 01:41:57.280 16931-16931/? E/studio.deploy: Could not get package user id: /system/bin/run-as: package not debuggable: com.satyamdorville.discover
2021-05-31 01:41:57.563 17402-17402/? E/rville.discove: Not starting debugger since process cannot load the jdwp agent.
2021-05-31 01:41:57.860 1816-1926/? E/SurfaceFlinger: ro.sf.lcd_density must be defined as a build property
2021-05-31 01:41:57.861 1816-2469/? E/SurfaceFlinger: ro.sf.lcd_density must be defined as a build property
2021-05-31 01:41:57.972 1779-17426/? E/ResolverController: No valid NAT64 prefix (101, <unspecified>/0)
2021-05-31 01:41:58.058 17402-17437/? E/unknown:ReactNative: ReactInstanceManager.createReactContext: mJSIModulePackage not null
2021-05-31 01:41:58.058 17402-17441/? E/ReactNativeJNI: logMarker CREATE_REACT_CONTEXT_END
2021-05-31 01:41:58.187 1795-2310/? E/GnssHAL_GnssInterface: gnssSvStatusCb: a: input svInfo.flags is 8
2021-05-31 01:41:58.187 1795-2310/? E/GnssHAL_GnssInterface: gnssSvStatusCb: b: input svInfo.flags is 8
2021-05-31 01:41:58.245 17402-17437/? E/unknown:ReactNative: ReactInstanceManager.createReactContext: ReactFeatureFlags.useTurboModules == false
2021-05-31 01:41:58.295 17402-17441/? E/ReactNativeJNI: logMarker RUN_JS_BUNDLE_START
2021-05-31 01:41:58.641 17402-17402/? E/unknown:ReactNative: Unable to launch logbox because react was unable to create the root view
2021-05-31 01:41:59.190 1795-2310/? E/GnssHAL_GnssInterface: gnssSvStatusCb: a: input svInfo.flags is 8
2021-05-31 01:41:59.190 1795-2310/? E/GnssHAL_GnssInterface: gnssSvStatusCb: b: input svInfo.flags is 8
2021-05-31 01:41:59.967 1779-17461/? E/ResolverController: No valid NAT64 prefix (101, <unspecified>/0)
2021-05-31 01:41:59.969 17402-17441/? E/ReactNativeJNI: logMarker RUN_JS_BUNDLE_END
2021-05-31 01:42:00.008 1779-17470/? E/ResolverController: No valid NAT64 prefix (101, <unspecified>/0)
```

I got a bit of that also :

```
E/NetRec: [1196] aqzc.c: Could not retrieve server token for package com.google.android.apps.gcs
    java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: uhf: 29503:
```

Here is some code :

build gradle top level

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.


buildscript {
    ext {
        RNNKotlinVersion = "1.4.21"
        buildToolsVersion = "30.0.0"
        minSdkVersion = 21
        compileSdkVersion = 30
        targetSdkVersion = 30
    }
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.0")
    classpath ("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.4.21")

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        maven {
            // All of React Native (JS, Obj-C sources, Android binaries) is installed from npm
            url("$rootDir/../node_modules/react-native/android")
        }
        maven {
            // Android JSC is installed from npm
            url("$rootDir/../node_modules/jsc-android/dist")
        }

        google()
        jcenter()
        maven { url 'https://www.jitpack.io' }
    }
}
```

build.gradle in /app

```
apply plugin: "com.android.application"
apply plugin: "kotlin-android"
apply plugin: "kotlin-android-extensions"
import com.android.build.OutputFile

/**
 * The react.gradle file registers a task for each build variant (e.g. bundleDebugJsAndAssets
 * and bundleReleaseJsAndAssets).
 * These basically call `react-native bundle` with the correct arguments during the Android build
 * cycle. By default, bundleDebugJsAndAssets is skipped, as in debug/dev mode we prefer to load the
 * bundle directly from the development server. Below you can see all the possible configurations
 * and their defaults. If you decide to add a configuration block, make sure to add it before the
 * `apply from: "../../node_modules/react-native/react.gradle"` line.
 *
 * project.ext.react = [
 *   // the name of the generated asset file containing your JS bundle
 *   bundleAssetName: "index.android.bundle",
 *
 *   // the entry file for bundle generation. If none specified and
 *   // "index.android.js" exists, it will be used. Otherwise "index.js" is
 *   // default. Can be overridden with ENTRY_FILE environment variable.
 *   entryFile: "index.android.js",
 *
 *   // https://reactnative.dev/docs/performance#enable-the-ram-format
 *   bundleCommand: "ram-bundle",
 *
 *   // whether to bundle JS and assets in debug mode
 *   bundleInDebug: false,
 *
 *   // whether to bundle JS and assets in release mode
 *   bundleInRelease: true,
 *
 *   // whether to bundle JS and assets in another build variant (if configured).
 *   // See http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide#TOC-Build-Variants
 *   // The configuration property can be in the following formats
 *   //         'bundleIn${productFlavor}${buildType}'
 *   //         'bundleIn${buildType}'
 *   // bundleInFreeDebug: true,
 *   // bundleInPaidRelease: true,
 *   // bundleInBeta: true,
 *
 *   // whether to disable dev mode in custom build variants (by default only disabled in release)
 *   // for example: to disable dev mode in the staging build type (if configured)
 *   devDisabledInStaging: true,
 *   // The configuration property can be in the following formats
 *   //         'devDisabledIn${productFlavor}${buildType}'
 *   //         'devDisabledIn${buildType}'
 *
 *   // the root of your project, i.e. where "package.json" lives
 *   root: "../../",
 *
 *   // where to put the JS bundle asset in debug mode
 *   jsBundleDirDebug: "$buildDir/intermediates/assets/debug",
 *
 *   // where to put the JS bundle asset in release mode
 *   jsBundleDirRelease: "$buildDir/intermediates/assets/release",
 *
 *   // where to put drawable resources / React Native assets, e.g. the ones you use via
 *   // require('./image.png')), in debug mode
 *   resourcesDirDebug: "$buildDir/intermediates/res/merged/debug",
 *
 *   // where to put drawable resources / React Native assets, e.g. the ones you use via
 *   // require('./image.png')), in release mode
 *   resourcesDirRelease: "$buildDir/intermediates/res/merged/release",
 *
 *   // by default the gradle tasks are skipped if none of the JS files or assets change; this means
 *   // that we don't look at files in android/ or ios/ to determine whether the tasks are up to
 *   // date; if you have any other folders that you want to ignore for performance reasons (gradle
 *   // indexes the entire tree), add them here. Alternatively, if you have JS files in android/
 *   // for example, you might want to remove it from here.
 *   inputExcludes: ["android/**", "ios/**"],
 *
 *   // override which node gets called and with what additional arguments
 *   nodeExecutableAndArgs: ["node"],
 *
 *   // supply additional arguments to the packager
 *   extraPackagerArgs: []
 * ]
 */

project.ext.react = [
    enableHermes: false
]

apply from: '../../node_modules/react-native-unimodules/gradle.groovy'
apply from: "../../node_modules/react-native/react.gradle"
apply from: "../../node_modules/expo-constants/scripts/get-app-config-android.gradle"
apply from: "../../node_modules/expo-updates/scripts/create-manifest-android.gradle"

/**
 * Set this to true to create two separate APKs instead of one:
 *   - An APK that only works on ARM devices
 *   - An APK that only works on x86 devices
 * The advantage is the size of the APK is reduced by about 4MB.
 * Upload all the APKs to the Play Store and people will download
 * the correct one based on the CPU architecture of their device.
 */
def enableSeparateBuildPerCPUArchitecture = false

/**
 * Run Proguard to shrink the Java bytecode in release builds.
 */
def enableProguardInReleaseBuilds = false

/**
 * The preferred build flavor of JavaScriptCore.
 *
 * For example, to use the international variant, you can use:
 * `def jscFlavor = 'org.webkit:android-jsc-intl:+'`
 *
 * The international variant includes ICU i18n library and necessary data
 * allowing to use e.g. `Date.toLocaleString` and `String.localeCompare` that
 * give correct results when using with locales other than en-US.  Note that
 * this variant is about 6MiB larger per architecture than default.
 */
def jscFlavor = 'org.webkit:android-jsc:+'

/**
 * Whether to enable the Hermes VM.
 *
 * This should be set on project.ext.react and mirrored here.  If it is not set
 * on project.ext.react, JavaScript will not be compiled to Hermes Bytecode
 * and the benefits of using Hermes will therefore be sharply reduced.
 */
def enableHermes = project.ext.react.get("enableHermes", false);

android {
    compileSdkVersion rootProject.ext.compileSdkVersion

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
kotlinOptions {
    jvmTarget = "1.8"
}
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId 'com.satyamdorville.discover'
        minSdkVersion rootProject.ext.minSdkVersion
        targetSdkVersion rootProject.ext.targetSdkVersion
        versionCode 15
        versionName "1.0.7"
    }
    splits {
        abi {
            reset()
            enable enableSeparateBuildPerCPUArchitecture
            universalApk false  // If true, also generate a universal APK
            include "armeabi-v7a", "x86", "arm64-v8a", "x86_64"
        }
    }
    signingConfigs {
        debug {
            storeFile file('debug.keystore')
            storePassword 'android'
            keyAlias 'androiddebugkey'
            keyPassword 'android'
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        debug {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }
        release {
            // Caution! In production, you need to generate your own keystore file.
            // see https://reactnative.dev/docs/signed-apk-android.
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
            minifyEnabled enableProguardInReleaseBuilds
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android.txt"), "proguard-rules.pro"
        }
    }

    // applicationVariants are e.g. debug, release
    applicationVariants.all { variant ->
        variant.outputs.each { output ->
            // For each separate APK per architecture, set a unique version code as described here:
            // https://developer.android.com/studio/build/configure-apk-splits.html
            def versionCodes = ["armeabi-v7a": 1, "x86": 2, "arm64-v8a": 3, "x86_64": 4]
            def abi = output.getFilter(OutputFile.ABI)
            if (abi != null) {  // null for the universal-debug, universal-release variants
                output.versionCodeOverride =
                        versionCodes.get(abi) * 1048576 + defaultConfig.versionCode
            }

        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
    //noinspection GradleDynamicVersion
    implementation "com.facebook.react:react-native:+"  // From node_modules
    implementation "androidx.swiperefreshlayout:swiperefreshlayout:1.0.0"
    debugImplementation("com.facebook.flipper:flipper:${FLIPPER_VERSION}") {
      exclude group:'com.facebook.fbjni'
    }
    debugImplementation("com.facebook.flipper:flipper-network-plugin:${FLIPPER_VERSION}") {
        exclude group:'com.facebook.flipper'
        exclude group:'com.squareup.okhttp3', module:'okhttp'
    }
    debugImplementation("com.facebook.flipper:flipper-fresco-plugin:${FLIPPER_VERSION}") {
        exclude group:'com.facebook.flipper'
    }
    addUnimodulesDependencies()

    if (enableHermes) {
        def hermesPath = "../../node_modules/hermes-engine/android/";
        debugImplementation files(hermesPath + "hermes-debug.aar")
        releaseImplementation files(hermesPath + "hermes-release.aar")
    } else {
        implementation jscFlavor
    }
}

// Run this once to be able to run the application with BUCK
// puts all compile dependencies into folder libs for BUCK to use
task copyDownloadableDepsToLibs(type: Copy) {
    from configurations.compile
    into 'libs'
}

apply from: file("../../node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-android/native_modules.gradle"); applyNativeModulesAppBuildGradle(project)
apply from: "./eas-build.gradle"
```

eas-build.gradle

```
// Build integration with EAS
apply plugin: "com.android.application"
apply plugin: "kotlin-android"
apply plugin: "kotlin-android-extensions"
import java.nio.file.Paths

android {
  compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
kotlinOptions {
    jvmTarget = "1.8"
}
defaultConfig {
        applicationId 'com.satyamdorville.discover'
        minSdkVersion rootProject.ext.minSdkVersion
        targetSdkVersion rootProject.ext.targetSdkVersion
        versionCode 15
        versionName "1.0.7"
    }
  signingConfigs {
    release {
      // This is necessary to avoid needing the user to define a release signing config manually
      // If no release config is defined, and this is not present, build for assembleRelease will crash
    }
  }

  buildTypes {
    release {
      // This is necessary to avoid needing the user to define a release build type manually
    }
  }
}

def isEasBuildConfigured = false

tasks.whenTaskAdded {
  def debug = gradle.startParameter.taskNames.any { it.toLowerCase().contains('debug') }

  if (debug) {
    return
  }

  // We only need to configure EAS build once
  if (isEasBuildConfigured) {
    return
  }

  isEasBuildConfigured = true;

  android.signingConfigs.release {
    def credentialsJson = rootProject.file("../credentials.json");

    if (credentialsJson.exists()) {
      if (storeFile && System.getenv("EAS_BUILD") != "true") {
        println("Path to release keystore file is already set, ignoring 'credentials.json'")
      } else {
        try {
          def credentials = new groovy.json.JsonSlurper().parse(credentialsJson)
          def keystorePath = Paths.get(credentials.android.keystore.keystorePath);
          def storeFilePath = keystorePath.isAbsolute()
            ? keystorePath
            : rootProject.file("..").toPath().resolve(keystorePath);

          storeFile storeFilePath.toFile()
          storePassword credentials.android.keystore.keystorePassword
          keyAlias credentials.android.keystore.keyAlias
          if (credentials.android.keystore.containsKey("keyPassword")) {
            keyPassword credentials.android.keystore.keyPassword
          } else {
            // key password is required by Gradle, but PKCS keystores don't have one
            // using the keystore password seems to satisfy the requirement
            keyPassword credentials.android.keystore.keystorePassword
          }
        } catch (Exception e) {
          println("An error occurred while parsing 'credentials.json': " + e.message)
        }
      }
    } else {
      if (storeFile == null) {
        println("Couldn't find a 'credentials.json' file, skipping release keystore configuration")
      }
    }
  }

  android.buildTypes.release {
    signingConfig android.signingConfigs.release
  }
}
```

My Android Manifest

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" package="com.satyamdorville.discover">
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE"/>
  <application android:name=".MainApplication" android:label="@string/app_name" android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher" android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round" android:allowBackup="true" android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <meta-data android:name="expo.modules.updates.EXPO_UPDATE_URL" android:value="https://exp.host/@satyamdorville/discover" />
    <meta-data android:name="expo.modules.updates.EXPO_SDK_VERSION" android:value="41.0.0" />
    <meta-data android:name="expo.modules.updates.ENABLED" android:value="true"/>
    <meta-data android:name="expo.modules.updates.EXPO_UPDATES_CHECK_ON_LAUNCH" android:value="ALWAYS"/>
    <meta-data android:name="expo.modules.updates.EXPO_UPDATES_LAUNCH_WAIT_MS" android:value="0"/>
    <meta-data android:name="expo.modules.updates.EXPO_RELEASE_CHANNEL" android:value="default" />

  <activity
    android:name=".MainActivity" android:label="@string/app_name" android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize|uiMode" android:launchMode="singleTask" android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize" android:theme="@style/Theme.App.SplashScreen" android:screenOrientation="portrait">
      <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
      </intent-filter>
      <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
        <data android:scheme="discover"/>
        <data android:scheme="com.satyamdorville.discover"/>
      </intent-filter>
      <intent-filter>
        <data android:scheme="discover"/>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
      </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name="com.facebook.react.devsupport.DevSettingsActivity"/>
  </application>
</manifest>
```

And EAS config json

```
{
  "builds": {
    "android": {
      "release": {
        "workflow": "generic",
        "withoutCredentials": true,
        "gradleCommand": ":app:assembleDebug",
        "artifactPath": "android/app/build/outputs/apk/debug/app-debug.apk"
      }
    },
    "ios": {
      "release": {
        "workflow": "generic"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Also my Main Application java

```
package com.satyamdorville.discover;

import android.app.Application;
import android.content.Context;
import android.net.Uri;

import com.facebook.react.PackageList;
import com.reactnativenavigation.NavigationApplication;
import com.facebook.react.ReactInstanceManager;
import com.facebook.react.ReactNativeHost;
import com.reactnativenavigation.react.NavigationReactNativeHost;
import com.facebook.react.ReactPackage;
import com.facebook.react.shell.MainReactPackage;
import com.facebook.soloader.SoLoader;
import com.satyamdorville.discover.generated.BasePackageList;

import org.unimodules.adapters.react.ReactAdapterPackage;
import org.unimodules.adapters.react.ModuleRegistryAdapter;
import org.unimodules.adapters.react.ReactModuleRegistryProvider;
import org.unimodules.core.interfaces.Package;
import org.unimodules.core.interfaces.SingletonModule;
import expo.modules.constants.ConstantsPackage;
import expo.modules.permissions.PermissionsPackage;
import expo.modules.filesystem.FileSystemPackage;
import expo.modules.updates.UpdatesController;

import com.facebook.react.bridge.JSIModulePackage;
import com.swmansion.reanimated.ReanimatedJSIModulePackage;

import java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import javax.annotation.Nullable;

public class MainApplication extends NavigationApplication {
  private final ReactModuleRegistryProvider mModuleRegistryProvider = new ReactModuleRegistryProvider(
    new BasePackageList().getPackageList()
  );

  private final ReactNativeHost mReactNativeHost = new NavigationReactNativeHost(this) {
    @Override
    public boolean getUseDeveloperSupport() {
      return BuildConfig.DEBUG;
    }

    @Override
    protected List<ReactPackage> getPackages() {
      List<ReactPackage> packages = new PackageList(this).getPackages();
      packages.add(new ModuleRegistryAdapter(mModuleRegistryProvider));
      return packages;
    }

    @Override
    protected String getJSMainModuleName() {
      return "Table Discover";
    }

    @Override
    protected JSIModulePackage getJSIModulePackage() {
      return new ReanimatedJSIModulePackage();
    }

    @Override
    protected @Nullable String getJSBundleFile() {
      if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) {
        return super.getJSBundleFile();
      } else {
        UpdatesController.initialize(this.getApplication().getApplicationContext());
        return UpdatesController.getInstance().getLaunchAssetFile();
      }
    }

    @Override
    protected @Nullable String getBundleAssetName() {
      if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) {
        return super.getBundleAssetName();
      } else {
        UpdatesController.initialize(this.getApplication().getApplicationContext());
        return UpdatesController.getInstance().getBundleAssetName();
      }
    }
  };

  @Override
  public ReactNativeHost getReactNativeHost() {
    return mReactNativeHost;
  }

  @Override
  public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    SoLoader.init(this, /* native exopackage */ false);

    if (!BuildConfig.DEBUG) {
      UpdatesController.initialize(this);
    }

    initializeFlipper(this, getReactNativeHost().getReactInstanceManager());
  }

  /**
   * Loads Flipper in React Native templates. Call this in the onCreate method with something like
   * initializeFlipper(this, getReactNativeHost().getReactInstanceManager());
   *
   * @param context
   * @param reactInstanceManager
   */
  private static void initializeFlipper(
      Context context, ReactInstanceManager reactInstanceManager) {
    if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) {
      try {
        /*
         We use reflection here to pick up the class that initializes Flipper,
        since Flipper library is not available in release mode
        */
        Class<?> aClass = Class.forName("com.satyamdorville.discover.ReactNativeFlipper");
        aClass
            .getMethod("initializeFlipper", Context.class, ReactInstanceManager.class);
             aClass.getMethod("initializeFlipper", Context.class, ReactInstanceManager.class).invoke(null, context,
            reactInstanceManager);      
            } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
      } catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
      } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
      } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
      }
    }
  }
}
```

And my activity java

```
package com.satyamdorville.discover;
import android.content.res.Configuration;
import android.content.Intent;

import android.os.Bundle;

import com.reactnativenavigation.NavigationActivity;
import com.facebook.react.ReactActivityDelegate;
import com.facebook.react.ReactRootView;
import com.swmansion.gesturehandler.react.RNGestureHandlerEnabledRootView;

import expo.modules.splashscreen.singletons.SplashScreen;
import expo.modules.splashscreen.SplashScreenImageResizeMode;


public class MainActivity extends NavigationActivity {

    // Added automatically by Expo Config
    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
        Intent intent = new Intent("onConfigurationChanged");
        intent.putExtra("newConfig", newConfig);
        sendBroadcast(intent);
    }

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(null);
    // SplashScreen.show(...) has to be called after super.onCreate(...)
    // Below line is handled by '@expo/configure-splash-screen' command and it's discouraged to modify it manually
    SplashScreen.show(this, SplashScreenImageResizeMode.CONTAIN, ReactRootView.class, false);
  }

protected String getMainComponentName() { 
    return "Table Discover"; 
    }
     
    

    protected ReactActivityDelegate createReactActivityDelegate() {
        return new ReactActivityDelegate(this, getMainComponentName()) {
            protected ReactRootView createRootView() {
                return new RNGestureHandlerEnabledRootView(MainActivity.this);
            }
        };
    }
}
```

Every bit of help and / or understanding is welcomed there as i fight with the current situation for several days....

Answer (score -1):

I have deleted ios / android folders.
I have ran expo eject again.
I have deleted everywhere in my code react-native-navigation which was the source of the problem.
It works !